# Why can't I iterate after an assignment in Raku?

Tags: raku

Given the following code, it seems that I cannot iterate over a Buf if it had been assigned to a variable, unless I cast it to a list, even though it's not a lazy sequence. What gives?

```
    my $file = open $path, bin => True;
    $_.chr.say for $file.read: 8; # works well

    my $test = $file.read: 8;
    $_.chr.say for $test; # fails with "No such method 'chr' for invocant of type 'Buf[uint8]'"
    $_.chr.say for $test.list; # works well
    $test.is-lazy.say; # False
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason it fails, is that:

```
my $test = $file.read: 8;
```

puts the `Buf` that is returned by `$file.read` into a [`Scalar`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Scalar) variable, aka inside a container.  And containerized is interpreted by `for` as itemized, to be considered a single item.  So with:

```
.chr.say for $test;
```

you're calling the `.chr` method on the whole `Buf`, rather than on the individual elements.

There are a number of solutions to this:

1. make sure there's no container:

```
my $test := $file.read: 8;
```

This makes sure there is no container by **binding** the `Buf`.

2. make it look like an array

```
my @test := $file.read: 8;
```

Same as 1 basically, make the `@test` be an alias for the `Buf`.  Note that this should also use binding, otherwise you'll get the same effect as you saw.

3. make it work like an Iterable

```
.chr.say for @$test;
```

By prefixing the `@` you're telling to iterate over it.  This is basically syntactic sugar for the `$test.list` workaround you already found.

Re the `$test.is-lazy.say`, that is `False` for just about anything, e.g. `42.is-lazy.say;  # False`, so that doesn't tell you very much :-)